# putting a text file into an array using jfilechooser for java

Tags: java, io, inputstream, jfilechooser

I keep on getting the array out bounds, as the student could have different number of grades and due to this if a student doesn't have a grade 3 but another student does,my program automatically crashes. What could I do to make the program have different number of grades depending on students.

```
public class StudentList  extends Component{

static  ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
public  static final int ARRAYMAX=4;

public void readStudent()throws Exception{

    File window = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    JFileChooser choice = new JFileChooser();
    choice.setCurrentDirectory(window);
    int option = choice.showOpenDialog(this);
    File selectedFile = choice.getSelectedFile();
    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    File studentFile = new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());

    Scanner in = new Scanner(studentFile);

     while (in.hasNext()) {
         String data = in.nextLine();

            String[] studentData = new String[ARRAYMAX];
            studentData = data.split("\\|");

                for(int i =0; i<ARRAYMAX; i++){
                    studentData[i] ="0";
               }

        String firstName = studentData[0];
        String lastName  = studentData[1];

        double grade1 = Double.parseDouble(studentData[2]);
        double grade2 = Double.parseDouble(studentData[3]);

        double grade3 = Double.parseDouble(studentData[4]);

        Student newStudent = new Student(firstName,lastName);
        newStudent.setGrades1(grade1);
        newStudent.setGrades2(grade2);
        newStudent.setGrades3(grade3);
     }

  }
```

}

Comment: studentData's length is equal to ARRAYMAX which is 4, but you're attempting to access studentData[4] which is the 5th index in the array. this will not work and you must change ARRAYMAX to 5 in order to access index 4. Arrays are 0 indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Default grades(grade1, grade2, etc.) to sensible values. Check length of studentData(`studentData.length`) before accessing it and setting grades.

On other hand, why use individual `grade` field/setters? Simply store all grades in a List or Array field and then access it for whatever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i understand you correctly, some of lines dont have 3rd grade. If so, you can check if it has a 3rd grade or not `public class StudentList extends Component{ static ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>(); public static final int ARRAYMAX=4; public void readStudent()throws Exception{ File window = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")); JFileChooser choice = new JFileChooser(); choice.setCurrentDirectory(window); int option = choice.showOpenDialog(this); File selectedFile = choice.getSelectedFile(); if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()); } File studentFile = new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()); Scanner in = new Scanner(studentFile); while (in.hasNext()) { String data = in.nextLine(); String[] studentData = new String[ARRAYMAX]; studentData = data.split("\\|"); for(int i =0; i<ARRAYMAX; i++){ studentData[i] ="0"; } String firstName = studentData[0]; String lastName = studentData[1]; double grade1 = Double.parseDouble(studentData[2]==null?"0":studentData[2]); double grade2 = Double.parseDouble(studentData[3]==null?"0":studentData[3]); double grade3 = Double.parseDouble(studentData[4]==null?"0":studentData[4] ); Student newStudent = new Student(firstName,lastName); newStudent.setGrades1(grade1); newStudent.setGrades2(grade2); newStudent.setGrades3(grade3); } }`